# Tricky parse query

Tags: android, parse-platform

i'm quite new to parse queries, so I would appreciate if you could give me some help.

I have a database like this:

```
ID - NAME - HOUR
07 - AAAA - 09:07
07 - AAAA - 09:15
08 - AAAA - 09:08
08 - AAAA - 09:09
09 - AAAA - 07:00
```

I need a query that return to me this:

```
ID - NAME - HOUR
07 - AAAA - 09:15
08 - AAAA - 09:09
09 - AAAA - 07:00
```

I'm already able to get the lastest hour for a determinated name, but when i put the ID, I got lost.

Thanks.

Comment: So you have entrys with the same id? How is that even possible? Check out what ID means first pls

Comment: ciao, are you trying to get FOR EACH "ID" the LATEST TIME?

Comment: Xx .. his own field is called "ID" I believe.  nothing wrong with that.

Comment: I called it id, but it's not the unique identifier, and yes @JoeBlow I'm trying for each "ID" last time

Comment: then just query all items and then in a for loop pick for every id the one with the latest time

Comment: @XxGoliathusxX Well, I'm working on an app that have to work fast in devices using 3G connection and you low processor capacity, so I'm trying to optimize my queries.

Comment: My SQL usage is long time ago. The only alternative i can think is sth like:
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID == XX AND max(HOUR)

Comment: Hi Xx ... this has **nothing to do** with SQL, it is totally unrelated to SQL.  This is NoSQL using a service called Parse.com (check it online).  Regarding your second-last comment, note that you would never, ever, ever, ever, ever, ever, ever, ever, ever, ever, ever, ever "query in a loop" when using a BAAS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ciao, the answer is unfortunately you CAN NOT "group" or "unique" with Parse.com - that's a fact unfortunately!

Standard procedure with Parse:

Simply get all items for "AAAA"

sort by both ID then backwards by HOUR.

IN YOUR APP, simply loop through and take only the first of each ID, dispose of other equal IDs.

(This is extremely easy to do in most environments, like Swift say.)

Unfortunately this is exactly what you have to do with Parse, for what you're trying to achieve.

(Myself - I don't even bother with the sort from Parse, I just get all "AAAA".  And I trivially sort and select on the app side.)

Hope it helps

Comment: So, I thank you, Now I won't spend lots of time in it! =D